# Deep reactivity of props in vuejs components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-props

I'm trying to build a simple page builder which has a row elements, its child column elements and  the last the component which I need to call. For this I designed and architecture where I'm having the dataset defined to the root component and pushing the data to its child elements via props. So let say I have a root component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button @click.prevent="addRowField"></button>
        <row-element v-if="elements.length" v-for="(row, index) in elements" :key="'row_index_'+index" :attrs="row.attrs" :child_components="row.child_components" :row_index="index"></row-element>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import RowElement from "../../Components/Builder/RowElement";

    export default {
        name: "edit",
        data(){
            return{
                elements: [],
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.listenToEvents();
        },
        components: {
            RowElement,
        },
        methods:{
            addRowField() {
                const row_element = {
                    component: 'row',
                    attrs: {},
                    child_components: [

                    ]
                }
                this.elements.push(row_element)
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

Here you can see I've a button where I'm trying to push the element and its elements are being passed to its child elements via props, so this `RowElement` component is having following code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <column-element v-if="child_components.length" v-for="(column,index) in child_components" :key="'column_index_'+index"  :attrs="column.attrs" :child_components="column.child_components" :row_index="row_index" :column_index="index"></column-element>
    </div>
    <button @click="addColumn"></button>
</template>

<script>
    import ColumnElement from "./ColumnElement";
    export default {
        name: "RowElement",
        components: {ColumnElement},
        props: {
            attrs: Object,
            child_components: Array,
            row_index: Number
        },
        methods:{
            addColumn(type, index) {
                this.selectColumn= false
                let column_element = {
                    component: 'column',
                    child_components: []
                };
                let component = {}

                //Some logic here then we are emitting event so that it goes to parent element and there it can push the columns

                eventBus.$emit('add-columns', {column: column_element, index: index});
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

So now I have to listen for event on root page so I'm having:

```
eventBus.$on('add-columns', (data) => {
    if(typeof this.elements[data.index] !== 'undefined')
        this.elements[data.index].child_components.push(data.column)
});
```

Now again I need these data accessible to again `ColumnComponent` so in columnComponent file I have:

```
<template>
    //some extra div to have extended features
    <builder-element
        v-if="!loading"
        v-for="(item, index) in child_components"
        :key="'element_index_'+index" :column_index="column_index"
        :element_index="index" class="border bg-white"
        :element="item" :row_index="row_index"
    >
    </builder-element>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "ColumnElement",
        props: {
            attrs: Object,
            child_components: Array,
            row_index: Number,
            column_index: Number
        },
    }
</script>
```

And my final `BuilderElement`

```
<template>
    <div v-if="typeof element.component !== 'undefined'" class="h-10 w-10 mt-1 mb-2 mr-3 cursor-pointer  font-bold text-white rounded-lg">
        <div>{{element.component}}</div>
        <img class="h-10 w-10 mr-3" :src="getDetails(item.component, 'icon')">
    </div>
    <div v-if="typeof element.component !== 'undefined'" class="flex-col text-left">
        <h5 class="text-blue-500 font-bold">{{getDetails(item.component, 'title')}}</h5>
        <p class="text-xs text-gray-600 mt-1">{{getDetails(item.component, 'desc')}}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "BuilderElement",
        data(){
            return{
                components:[
                    {id: 1, title:'Row', icon:'/project-assets/images/row.png', desc:'Place content elements inside the row', component_name: 'row'},
                    //list of rest all the components available
                ]
            }
        },
        props: {
            element: Object,
            row_index: Number,
            column_index: Number,
            element_index: Number,
        },
        methods:{
            addElement(item,index){
                //Some logic to find out details
                let component_element = {
                    component: item.component_name,
                    attrs: {},
                    child_components: [
                    ]
                }

                eventBus.$emit('add-component', {component: component_element, row_index: this.row_index, column_index: this.column_index, element_index: this.element_index});

            },
            getDetails(component, data) {
                let index = _.findIndex(this.components, (a) => {
                    return a.component_name === component;
                })
                console.log('Component'+ component);
                console.log('Index '+index);
                if(index > -1) {
                    let component_details = this.components[index];
                    return component_details[data];
                }
                else
                    return null;
            },
        },
    }
</script>
```

As you can see I'm again emitting the event named `add-component` which is again listened in the root component so for this is made following listener:

```
eventBus.$on('add-component', (data) => {
    this.elements[data.row_index].child_components[data.column_index].child_components[data.element_index] = data.component
});
```

which shows the data set in my `vue-devtools` but it is not appearing in the builder element:

Images FYR:

This is my root component:

[image: Root element]

This is my RowComponent:

[image: Row component]

This is my ColumnComponent:

[image: Column component]

This is my builder element:

[image: Last builder element]

I don't know why this data not getting passed to its child component, I mean last component is not reactive to props, any better idea is really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Will take a while to replicate the problem but have you tried setting dynamic properties using `this.$set`?

Comment: @pai.not.pi do you have any example? in fiddle/jsbin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the way you're setting your data in the `addComponent` method.

Vue cannot pick up changes when you change an array by directly modifying it's index, something like,

```
arr[0] = 10
```

As defined in their [change detection guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection) for array mutations,

> Vue wraps an observed array’s mutation methods so they will also
> trigger view updates. The wrapped methods are:
>
> 1. push()
> 2. pop()
> 3. shift()
> 4. unshift()
> 5. splice()
> 6. sort()
> 7. reverse()

So you can change.

```
this.elements[data.row_index].child_components[data.column_index].child_components[data.element_index] = data.component
```

To,

```
this.elements[data.row_index].child_components[data.column_index].child_components.splice(data.element_index, 1, data.component);
```